# Finding out which Row in a Table is locked - SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, locking

I have the following query which returns any locks on a specific table. However, I need it to give more information. I need to know which row is currently being locked.

```
    SELECT 
 DB_NAME(resource_database_id)
 , s.original_login_name
 , s.status
 , s.program_name
 , s.host_name
 ,*
from 
 sys.dm_tran_locks dbl
  JOIN sys.dm_exec_sessions s ON dbl.request_session_id = s.session_id
where 
  resource_associated_entity_id = object_id('dbname.scheme.table')AND  DB_NAME(resource_database_id) = 'dbname'
```

This query works for showing when there is a lock. I just need a bit more information. As an example, the table I'm looking at contains a lot of orders. If someone is sat in one of those orders within the application. The row will be locked, I need the query to show the order-No of the row that is locked.

EDIT: Attempts Below -

```
    select *
from db.scheme.table
where %%lockres%% in
(
select l.resource_description
from sys.dm_tran_locks as l
where l.resource_type in ('RID')
);
```

The above returns the row I'm expecting it to return but it will also return a lot of older rows within the table that I wouldn't expect it to. It however, seems close to what I need. With the suggestions from the answer below I couldn't get them to return any rows. I feel like a where statement on the above is what I'm missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

adhoc %%lockres%% row-level locks (not for constant monitoring etc.)

```
set transaction isolation level read uncommitted;

select *
from dbX.schemaY.tableZ 
where %%lockres%% in 
(
    select l.resource_description
    from sys.dm_tran_locks as l
    join sys.partitions as p on l.resource_associated_entity_id = p.partition_id
    where l.resource_type in ('KEY', 'RID')
    and p.object_id = object_id('dbX.schemaY.tableZ')
);

--demo
use tempdb
go

create table dbo.testtableX
(
    id int constraint pkclusteredid primary key clustered,
    thename nvarchar(128)
);
go

insert into dbo.testtableX(id, thename)
select object_id, name
from sys.objects
go

--select *
--from  dbo.testtableX;

--lock some rows
begin transaction
update dbo.testtableX with(rowlock)
set thename = thename+'update'
where id in (44, 45, 46)

--..or in another ssms windows
select 'locked rows', *
from dbo.testtableX with(nolock)
where %%lockres%% in
(
select l.resource_description
from sys.dm_tran_locks as l
where l.resource_type in ('KEY', 'RID') --index lock, KEY
);

select l.resource_description, *
from sys.dm_tran_locks as l
where l.resource_type in ('KEY', 'RID') --index lock, KEY

rollback transaction
go

--to heap
alter table dbo.testtableX drop constraint pkclusteredid;

--...repeat
begin transaction
update dbo.testtableX with(rowlock)
set thename = thename+'update'
where id in (54, 55, 56)

--..or in another ssms windows
select 'locked rows', *
from dbo.testtableX with(nolock)
where %%lockres%% in
(
select l.resource_description
from sys.dm_tran_locks as l
where l.resource_type in ('KEY', 'RID') --row identifier lock, RID
);

select l.resource_description, *
from sys.dm_tran_locks as l
where l.resource_type in ('KEY', 'RID') --RID

rollback transaction
go

drop table dbo.testtableX;
go
```

Comment: I've tried running this but I'm getting no rows returned even though I'm sat in the row in my application. Any ideas?

Comment: there is a join on sys.partitions, have you tried it in the scope of dbX? use dbX;...select

Comment: Still not returning any rows - I have edited the question to show my attempts